# Spring Boot Microservice zuul Forwarding error

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-zuul

I have created micro service using spring boot and implment zuul proxy so when I call url via zuul proxy and somehow my service is down I get com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException

> com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error at
> org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:198)
> ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE] at
> org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:173)
> ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE] at
> org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:119)
> ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE] at
> com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:117)
> ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1] at
> com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193)
> ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1] at
> com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157)
> ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1] at
> com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118)
> ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1] at
> com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96)
> ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1] at
> com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116)
> ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1] at
> com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81)
> ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1] at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:166)
> [spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE] at
> org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:45)
> [spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE] at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
> [spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE] at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
> [spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE] at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
> [spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE] at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> [spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE] at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
> [spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE] at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> [spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE] at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Zuul API gateway** has been deprecated and now in maintenance mode. so it not recommended to use it.

You should use latest **Spring Cloud Gatway** in your project. if you    want to use gateway

learn more about spring cloud gateway here :https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway